# Can't block certain port on my linux server

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to block my server from getting requests on port 8001.
I ran `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8001 -j DROP`, then I ran `netstat -nlp` to see if the port is still listening.
The output was:

```
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::7777                 :::*                    LISTEN      1173/node       
tcp6       0      0 :::10050                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39192           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

It's seems that the port is still open and listening to requests.
How can I close it?

Answer (score 2):

I may be suffering from a misunderstanding (if so, people will tell me!)

`iptables` sets up firewall rules, and you have configured the firewall not to pass on items directed to port 8001

`netstat` shows ports that programs are listening to

So, your firewall is not allowing port 8001 through, but a program is listening for pings on that port.  There is no conflict here - if you want your program not to listen to the port, close the program.

If you are interested in what rules that you have active in the firewall, look at `iptables -L` or `iptables -S`